# Why is the Illustrator shortcut for "Font Size Step Up" not working?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts

I am trying to Increase font size using the short cut for Font Size Step Up/Down

```
Alt+Shift+Ctrl+.
Alt+Shift+Ctrl+,
```

But neither are working, I have tried on both Area Type, Point Type, text selected, and unselected.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: No idea.. it *should* work. Perhaps some basic maintenance.. try a new document. delete prefs etc...

Comment: It depends on what keyboard lsyout you have.

Comment: @joojaa I don't think that is it, I don't really see how that would affect it. A period and comma is a period and comma on all keyboards, I am using Touch Portal as well, which has the shortcut programmed in as it is in Illustrator and it's not working.

Comment: @Scott tried that, no luck. Even tried changing the shortcut to something else, still not working

Comment: @AasimAzam not all east asian keyboards have this feature. A systemwide issue in adobes system is that you cant use shortcuts if the symbol is behind a modifer. Which is the grater than and less than wont work on my keyboard layout as a shortcut.

Comment: @joojaa this is the default shortcut for these actions, so if that is a systemwide restriction, then why have that shortcut, it makes no sense. It also does not work if I assign a different shortcut to it.

Comment: welcome to the world of adobe. There are even a number of keyboard shortcuts that can not be changed that can not be used in most european keyboards in both illustrator and photoshop. This has been complained for over 25 years. Anyway back to your problem. Are you pressing this shortcut while while typing text?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but you can try Edit ---> Preferences --> Type ---> and make sure that Size/Leading is 1pt or more, not zero.